# Why does my Google App Engine app use an old version of OpenSSL?

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, openssl

I have

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

In my app.yaml file

I print out

```
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
```

In my main.py file, which is a flask app. When I run main.py using python, the program prints out

```
'OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018'
```

But when I run the app using dev_appserver.py, it prints out

```
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

Why is it using an older version of open ssl? I think this is leading to this error that I get when I try to send a message using Twilio

```
TwilioRestException: HTTP 426 error: Unable to create record: Upgrade Required
```

Comment: Are both app engine services on the same project? As you mention on your question [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/ssl_support#specifying_the_ssl_library) mentions it should have the same SSL library

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the gcloud tools don't install any version of OpenSSL on your computer, and instead use the version of OpenSSL that is already there as part of your existing Python installation.

The version of OpenSSL used with dev_appserver.py thus wouldn't be the same one that is used in production.

The difference between main.py and dev_appserver.py is likely caused by different different path configurations.  Those two versions of OpenSSL are somewhere on your computer and the path configuration picks up one versus the other.

Best way to check is to log the OpenSSL version in your production environment.